# How Can I split a string by the character "

Tags: go, split

[image]

That is what I have, and I tried to split like:
(Using Golang)

```
idPost = strings.Split(idPost,'"')
```

but the compiler said IncompatibleAssign using '"'.

Comment: `Split` takes a `string` as its second argument. Single quotes are for [`rune` literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Rune_literals). Use backticks for ["raw" string literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals) or double quotes for interpreted string literals with a backslash to escape the double quote inside.

Comment: Can you include a complete fragment of code in your question? You have two image links and one line of code, and the code in the images doesn't make sense on its own because one can't tell if ObjectID is a type with underlying string type, or a function.

Comment: Using images for code is bad for two reasons -- it's hard for people to test your code without retyping it themselves, and also it's inaccessible for screen readers (and generally for people who don't have great eyesight). Here's the stackoverflow help page on making a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `ObjectID` is not a string. It's an `ObjectID`. If you want the string version of it you can use `idPost.Hex()`.

Answer (score 8):

Use a back quote instead of an apostrophe, example:

```
idPost = strings.Split(idPost,`"`)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape it, so your question is *how to escape characters in go*.

[Escapes and multiline strings](https://yourbasic.org/golang/multiline-string/)

You will find this is similar across many languages:

```
dPost = strings.Split(idPost,"\"")
```