# How Can I receive params by Form-Data Golang

Tags: go, form-data

[image]

[image]

I´m trying like this, but mensaje is empty, How Can I receive the information? (Golang)

Comment: Use `ParseMultipartForm` instead of `ParseForm`.

Comment: And please do *NOT* post images. Post the text of the code instead. The reasons for that have already been explained to you by Paul Hankin in a comment to your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183439/how-can-i-split-a-string-by-the-character?noredirect=1#comment125827770_71183439

Answer (score 2):

You can find full answer on your question in this thread:
[In Go's http package, how do I get the query string on a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407719/in-gos-http-package-how-do-i-get-the-query-string-on-a-post-request)

tldr:

```
value := r.FormValue("field")
```